# 'unknown host service' when listing devices using SharpAdbClient on a Mac

Tags: .net, macos, adb

We're using AdbClient to get the first available device on which to run our Xamarin UITests.

The following code:

```
var device = AdbClient.Instance.GetDevices().ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

results in the error:

> An error occurred while reading a response from ADB: unknown host service

I can list devices in a Terminal with *adb devices*, and this works on other Macs

adb version in a command prompt gives:

> Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
>   Version 29.0.1-5644136

and we're using SharpAdbClient 2.2.16

Anyone seen this and got a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like SharpAdbClient is incompatible with ADB 1.0.41 - see [this issue](https://github.com/quamotion/madb/issues/147). There's a PR for SharpAdbClient fixing it.

Comment: Version 2.2.32 of SharpAdbClient should fix this.